# Match two digit numbers between two hypens

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following regex:

```
(?:-)[0-9]{2}(?=-)
```

To match the month of the following string:

```
2015-11-24T06:46:43.383Z
```

It works ... almost:

```
-11
```

It's including the left hypen. How to match only the `11` (two digit number)?

Comment: You can simply use `\-([0-9]{2})\-`. But I think you can simply use language inbuilt function for parsing a date

Comment: Use capturing group [`-([0-9]{2})-`](https://regex101.com/r/rM1jW8/2)

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: @alexchenco Use `new Date('2015-11-24T06:46:43.383Z').getMonth();`

Comment: You can use solution given by @Tushar ...the capturing group or the other one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word boundaries work:

```
"2015-11-24T06:46:43.383Z".match(/\b\d{2}\b/)[0]
#=> "11"
```

If it has to be hyphens:

```
"2015-11-24T06:46:43.383Z".match(/-(\d{2})-/)[1]
#=> "11"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use RegEx**, use `Date()` in JavaScript.

```
var month = new Date('2015-11-24T06:46:43.383Z').getMonth();
```

Note that month is zero-based index, so `getMonth` will return month less than the passed month.

If you **still** want to use regex, use capturing groups

```
'2015-11-24T06:46:43.383Z'.match(/-([0-9]{2})-/)[1];
```